# DynamoDB avoiding SCAN for time-series dataset

Tags: time-series, amazon-dynamodb

I'm interested in counting user interactions with uniquely identifiable resources between two points in time.

My use cases are:

1. Retrieve the total count for an individual `resourceId` (between time x and time y)
2. Produce a list of the top `resourceId`s ordered by count (between time x and time y)

Ideally I'd like to achieve this using DynamoDB. Sorting time series data in dynamo looks to have it's challenges and I'm running into some anti-best-practices whilst attempting to model the data.

### Data model so far

A downsampled table could look like this, where `count` is then number of interactions with a `resourceId` within the bounds of a `timebin`.

```
| resourceId    | timebin   | count |
|---------------|-----------|-------|
|(Partition Key)| (Sort Key)|       |
```

The total interaction count for each resource is the sum of the count attribute in each of items with the same `resourceId`. As an unbounded "all time" count is of interest, older events will never become obsolete, but they can be further downsampled and rolled into larger timebins.

With the above schema **use case 1** is fulfilled by queuing a resource using it's hash key and enforcing time constraints using the sort key. The total count can then be calculated application side.

For **use case 2**, I'm looking to achieve the equivalent of an SQL `GROUP BY resourceId, SUM(count)`. To do this the database needs to return all of the items that match the provided `timebin` constraints, regardless of `resourceId`. Grouping and summing of counts can then be performed application side.

**Problem:** With the above schema a full table scan is required to do this.

This is obviously something I would like to avoid.

### Possible solutions

1. Heavily cache the query for **use case 2**, so that scan is used, but only rarely (eg once a day).
2. Maintain an aggregate table, with for example, predefined `timeRange`s as the Partition Key and the corresponding `count` as the Sort Key.

i.e.

```
| resourceId | timeRange (partition)  | count (sort) |
|------------|------------------------|--------------|
|  1234      | "all_time"             | 9999         |
|  1234      | "past_day"             | 533          |
```

Here, "all_time" has a fixed FROM date, so could be incremented each time a `resourceId` event is received. "past_day", however, has a moving FROM date so would need to be regularly re-aggregated using updated FROM and TO markers.

### My Question

Is there a more efficient way to model this data?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the table with the resourceId being the hash key of the table, if you are performing aggregations within a single hash key this can be accomplished with a query.  Additionally if timebin, the range key, can be compared using greater than and less than operators you will be able to directly get to the records that you want with an efficient query and then sum up the counts on the application side.

However, this will not accomplish your second point so additional work will be required to meet both requirements.

---

Maintaining an aggregate table seems like the logical approach for a global leader board.  I'd recommend using DynamoDB Streams with AWS Lambda to maintain that aggregate table in near-real-time.  This follows the AWS best practices.

---

The periodic scan and aggregate approach is also valid and depending on your table size may be more practical since it is a more straight forward to implement, but there are a number of things to watch out for...

Make sure the process that scans is separate from your main application execution logic.  Populating this cache in real time would not be practical.  Table scans are only practical for real time requests if the number of items in the table is just a few hundred or less.

Make sure you rate limit your scan so that this process doesn't consume all of the IOPS.  Alternatively you could substantially raise the IOPS during this time period then lower then back once the process completes.  Another alternative would be to make a GSI that is as narrow as possible to scan, dedicating the GSI to this process would avoid needing to rate limit as it could consume all of the IOPS it wants without impacting other users of the table.